# Not getting the required interface everytime i search using/admin ,

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am following a yt tutorial on django(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm1mokevMWk)
where the tutor searches   http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin and gets the required interface
(It starts around 49:00)
everytime i search  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
i get a
DoesNotExist at /admin

but when i search http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/nw/
i get the required interface

A question exactly same as  mine has been asked before  but the thing is i did not make the same error as that person did

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


from .models import  ToDoList,Items

def index(response,name):
    ls=ToDoList.objects.get(name=name)
    item=ls.items_set.get(id=1)
    
    return HttpResponse("<h1>%s</h1><br></br><p>%s</p>"%(ls.name,str(item.text))) 

# Create your views here.
```

this is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("main.url")),
]
```

this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
class ToDoList(models.Model):
       name=models.CharField(max_length=200) 

       def __str__(self):

           return self.name

class Items(models.Model):
    todolist=models.ForeignKey(ToDoList,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    complete=models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: trailing slash in the url

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Cant believe i made such a silly error..

Answer (score 0):

I shouldnt have added the '/ ' in  /admin which is  inside the urls.py file